# Unable to run macro from java code

Tags: java, vba, excel

Below is my vb script that i want to run from my javacode. I am calling it using the below command 
        filePath = "D:\myVBS.vbs";

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);
```

i see the below error : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\myVBS.vbs": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

```js
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\easyAutomation2017\GoEasy\requiredSource\TestData1.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Run "TestData1.xlsm!refreshXLS"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

After googling i understood that this is the problem: You cannot run a shell script on Windows directly as it is no executable in the Windows sense

So how do i run it.

Please help!!
Thanks

Comment: Are you maybe running a 32-bit JVM and a 64-bit Excel or the way round?

Comment: Ok, how do i check that

Comment: Can you run the script manually, i.e. from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a vbs script, you need to run `Wscript.exe` and pass the vbs file as a parameter.

For example,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"C:\\Windows\\System32\\wscript.exe", "D:\\myVBS.vbs"});
```

Comment: on executing the above statement i got below error:java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "c:\windows\wscript.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified. Although i have given the right file path

Comment: Does `c:\\windows\\wscript.exe` definitely exist at that location?  I only put that as an example.

Comment: Thanks steve.. I updated the fielpath C:\\Windows\\System32\\wscript.exe and it works !!!!